# Delphi 6 convert ucs-2 little endian file to utf8

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-6

i am trying to import a csv file that has ucs2 little endian encoding. I am using a jedi compnonent(jvCsvDataset) for collecting-manipulating the data. The component cannot read the data with this encoding and i need to convert it to utf8. The thing is that i need to do it within delphi 6.

Are you aware of a "ucs2decode" function or any other method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use WideCharToMultiByte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file in a WideString, then use UTF8Encode, perhaps like this:

```
function ReadUCS2FileToUTF8(const FilePath: string): UTF8String;
var
  f: TFileStream;
  d: WideString;
begin
  f := TFileStream.Create(FilePath, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    SetLength(d, f.Size div SizeOf(WideChar));
    if Length(d) > 0 then
      f.ReadBuffer(d[1], Length(d) * SizeOf(WideChar));
  finally
    f.Free;
  end;
  Result := UTF8Encode(d);
end;
```

Comment: Note that `UTF8Encode()` and `UTF8Decode()` in Delphi 6 are incomplete.  They implement UTF-8 manually and only handle UTF-8 byte sequences up to 3 bytes (Unicode codepoints `U-0000` to `U+FFFF` but not any higher). So, to handle higher codepoints, you will have to use `WideCharToMultiByte()` and `MultiByteToWideChar()` directly (which `UTF8Encode()` and `UTF8Decode()` were updated in a later Delphi version to use).